# How to make a zoom effect on part of an image?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to implement a zoom effect on certain areas of the image on hover. I tried to do it but can't think of a correct solution.
let's say I can't enlarge the top right corner.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  const img = document.querySelector('img');
  
  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const { left, top, width, height } = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = ((e.pageX - left) / width) * 100;
    const y = ((e.pageY - top) / height) * 100;
    const styles = `transform: scale(2); transform-origin: ${x}px ${y}px`;
    img.style = styles;
  }
  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
  img.style = '';
  console.log('leave');
  }
  wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => handleMouseMove(e));
  wrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/adorable-brown-white-basenji-dog-smiling-giving-high-five-isolated-white_346278-1657.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1449299337.1618704000" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_magnifier_glass.asp

Answer (score 1):

I could understand your objective. The principal error was that you had been trying to update the zoom in basis of the current position of the image, which was constantly changing because you were changing the image properties.

In my solution I used the `left`, and `top` variables to make it the most generic possible, it could be easier in `React.js` in my opinion.

I take the top and left position on the first load, that the real solution.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  const img = document.querySelector('img');
  
    const { left, top } = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
    
  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
     const x = (e.pageX - left);
    const y = (e.pageY - top);
     const styles = `transform: scale(2); transform-origin: ${x}px ${y}px`;
     img.style = styles;
  }
  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
  img.style = '';
  }
  wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => handleMouseMove(e));
  wrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/adorable-brown-white-basenji-dog-smiling-giving-high-five-isolated-white_346278-1657.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1449299337.1618704000" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: My understanding of the question is that they are trying zoom only on a specific part of the image, not entire image itself...

Answer (score 0):

You made the calculations way more complicated than you had to.

I changed ...

```
const x = ((e.pageX - left) / width) * 100;
const y = ((e.pageY - top) / height) * 100;
```

... to ...

```
const x = e.pageX - left;
const y = e.pageY - top;
```

but the real magic happens when I added `pointer-events: none;` to `img` so it's always sending in `.wrapper` as `e.target`.

NOTE: the zoom functionality bugs out if the image is "over" the edge of the page, i.e. if you need to scroll down to see the full image. This happens in the original code as well. Just a heads up.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  const img = document.querySelector('img');
  
  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const { left, top, width, height } = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.pageX - left;
    const y = e.pageY - top;
    const styles = `transform: scale(2); transform-origin: ${x}px ${y}px`;
    img.style = styles;
  }
  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
  img.style = '';
  }
  wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => handleMouseMove(e));
  wrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/adorable-brown-white-basenji-dog-smiling-giving-high-five-isolated-white_346278-1657.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1449299337.1618704000" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: It's enlarges entire image, not a specific part of it.